# How do I stack two rows on top of each other using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to create a page that has 3 divs on it containing different things like text etc.
And I want to use Bootstrap so that it's mobile friendly as well.

But I can't seem to get it right using the Bootstrap grid system because I don't know how to stack two rows on to of each other.

Here is the idea, I want to stack two divs on top of each other on the left side only taking up 3 or 4 of the 12 columns and then have the big div in the middle of the screen.

[image]

The blue part is te div `frontSection`

```css
body {
    background: red;
}

.frontSection {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #3498db;
}


.myRow {
    border: red dotted 3px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.myCol {
    border: greenyellow dotted 3px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #2ecc71;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
        <div class="frontSection">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-center flex-fill myRow">
                    <div class="col-3 myCol">
                        
                        <div class="col-3 myCol">

                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-3 myCol">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-9 myCol">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Difficult to know what you want exactly, the picture is the result wanted ?

Comment: Yes sir, that is correct, the picture is a demonstration of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dw6amht/1/)

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="frontSection">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center flex-fill myRow">
      <div class="col-3 myCol">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 myCol">

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 myCol">

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div class="col-9 myCol">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

style.css

```
body {
  background: red;
}

.frontSection {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}


.myRow {
  border: red dotted 3px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.myCol {
  border: greenyellow dotted 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #2ecc71;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what I posted?

Comment: I have added `row` div so also added `col-xs-3` so that they will stack on each other

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and tell me if I get answered your question

```css
body {
    background: red;
}

.frontSection {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #3498db;
}


.myRow {
    border: red dotted 3px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.myCol {
    border: greenyellow dotted 3px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #2ecc71;
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  
}
.myCol--right {
    height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
        <div class="frontSection">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row align-items-end flex-fill myRow">
                    <div class="col-3 ">  
                             <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-12 myCol">
                                  </div>                        
                                  <div class="col-12 myCol">
                                  </div>
                             </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-2 offset-1 align-items-baseline myCol myCol--right">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```